# Can a JavaScript object be considered a plain dictionary?

Tags: javascript, oop

Today I heard that a JavaScript object is no more than a plain dictionary (taking as a reference the python dictionary)

I think it's a wrong idea, but I did not know how to answer to that.

So, **can you give me reasons why objects are not simple and dry dictionaries**?

- My first idea: prototypical inheritance.
- ...

Comment: It depends on what does mean "simple and dry" but aren't you happy with your first idea ?

Comment: You should probably ask this on Programmers Stack Exchange: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dystroy I mean that the object posibilities are more than just a group of data as hash table.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Well, do dictionary items have an implicit `this` reference to the dictionary?</strike>

If not, then a Javascript object is a bit more than a plain dictionary.

As dystroy points out, `this` is created by using a function to create the object, so it is probably more of a closure around the object.

So in that case, yes, an object is probably very much a dictionary :/

Comment: No, they don't have. But if you construct an object with literal notation `var obj = {a: ..., b: ...}` you don't have either a reference to `this`

Comment: `this` is the context, it's more a property of function execution than of objects.

Comment: Your right dystroy ;)  My mistake, this probably is a closure around the object.